# how to merge json array using java?

Tags: java, android, arrays, json

I am working on android studio.

I have two json arrays such as...

***jsonArray1:***

```
[
  {"file":"ay.m4a", "version":"5"}, 
  {"file":"kt.m4a", "version":"5"}
]
```

***jsonArray2:***

```
[
  {"file":"hh.m4a", "version":"7"}, 
  {"file":"sh.m4a", "version":"7"}
]
```

Then, I want to merge these arrays like this...

***jsonArrayMerged:***

```
[
  {"file":"ay.m4a", "version":"5"}, 
  {"file":"kt.m4a", "version":"5"}, 
  {"file":"hh.m4a", "version":"7"}, 
  {"file":"sh.m4a", "version":"7"}
]
```

How can I do this?

Comment: can't just instantiate two JSONArray and then add the contents of one to another?

Comment: create one new array and retrieve an object from your previous arrays and `put` into a newly created array

Comment: Try this link (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7940711/in-java-how-can-i-combine-two-json-arrays-of-objects)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try below code, This will give your desired result.

```
JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray();
JSONArray jsonArray1 = new JSONArray();
try {
    for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray1.length(); i++) {
        JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray1.getJSONObject(i);
        jsonArray.put(jsonObject);
    }
} catch (JSONException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Now use `jsonArray` which is having all merged jsonObject