# How to merge two JSON objects in Java

Tags: java, json

I am trying to merge two JSON objects, to create combined JSON file, for service usage.

First object:

```
{
    "reportRecords": [
        {
            "oldAgNumber": "00081433",
            "newAgNumber": "00064210",
            "loadStatus": "Y",
        },
        {
            "oldAgNumber": "9945",
            "newAgNumber": "00064211",
            "loadStatus": "Y",
        }
    ]
}
```

Second object:

```
{
    "reportRecords": [
        {
            "oldAgNumber": "61699",
            "newAgNumber": "00064211",
            "loadStatus": "Y",              
        },
        {
            "oldAgNumber": "4564",
            "newAgNumber": "00064211",
            "loadStatus": "Y",              
        }
    ]
}
```

Final outcome i want to have:

```
{
    "reportRecords": [
        {
            "oldAgNumber": "00081433",
            "newAgNumber": "00064210",
            "loadStatus": "Y",
        },
        {
            "oldAgNumber": "9945",
            "newAgNumber": "00064211",
            "loadStatus": "Y",
        },
        {
            "oldAgNumber": "61699",
            "newAgNumber": "00064211",
            "loadStatus": "Y",              
        },
        {
            "oldAgNumber": "4564",
            "newAgNumber": "00064211",
            "loadStatus": "Y",              
        }
    ]
}
```

Basically, both are same objects, but generated at different time so need to combine to create just one file.

####################################
Here is the code that is working - is there a better way to make it work?

```
// This is json object1  ->getReportHistory
            JsonObject reportjsonobject = new JsonParser().parse(getReportHistory).getAsJsonObject();
            JsonArray jsonArray = reportjsonobject.getAsJsonArray("reportRecords");
            // // This is json object2  ->newReportFile
            JsonObject newjsonObject = new JsonParser().parse(newReportFile).getAsJsonObject();
            JsonArray newjsonArray = newjsonObject.getAsJsonArray("reportRecords");

            //add new copy agency data to history report
            jsonArray.addAll(newjsonArray);

            //Create new json object
            JsonObject finaljsonObject = new JsonObject();

            try {
                //add json array to new obeject.
                finaljsonObject.add("reportRecords", jsonArray);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                logger.debug("json merge exception:" + e);
            }
            return finaljsonObject;
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to merge json array using java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46361269/how-to-merge-json-array-using-java)

Comment: Take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46361269/how-to-merge-json-array-using-java) question.

Comment: Load both to a list. Use `addAll`, return to JSON... What is the issue you are having? If you would like to ask a Java question, perhaps show your Java code so far?

Comment: Thank you guys for your response. special thanks to OneCricketeer for idea.