# Merging json objects in java

Tags: java, json, list, arraylist, merge

I have `List` of json objects and `List` of strings:

`List<Object1> list1` with this parameters: `Name` , `Age`.

`List<String> list2` with parameters: `Surname`;

so i want to create List of Objects in this format:

Surname from the `List1` and Name and Age from the `List2`

```
List 1 = [{Name: "John"; Age:28;}, {Name: "Mery" Age:22}]
List 2 = [{Surname: "Junior"}, {Surname: "Constant"}]
List 3 = [{Surname: "Junior" Name:"John" Age: 28} , {Surname:"Constant" , Name:"Mery", Age:22}]
```

So how to create the third List?

Comment: And your question is?

Comment: I want to know how to create the third list

Comment: You'll need to write some code.

Comment: ..and define some classes to rapresent your objects.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [In Java, how can I combine two JSON arrays of objects?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7940711/in-java-how-can-i-combine-two-json-arrays-of-objects)

Comment: Its not the same question. There is merging two string and here i have List of objects and List of Strings, and i want to create List of Objects

Answer (score 1):

You can create a new object which has the three properties `Object3: {Surname, Name, Age}` and make a new list and use a loop to read values for `list1` and `list2` and populate the third list.( Assuming they are of the same size )

```
public class Object3 {
     String Sirname; 
     String Name; 
     String Age;

     public Object3(String sirname, String name, String age) {
         Sirname = sirname;
         Name = name;
         Age = age;
     }
     //getters and setters
}
```

Then loop over them:

```
public List<Object3> mergeLists(List<Object1> list1, List<String> list2){
    int size =  list1.size();
    List<Object3> list3 = new ArrayList<Object3>(size);
    for ( int i = 0; i < size; i++){
        Object3 obj = new Object3(list2.get(i),
            list1.get(i).getName(),
            list1.get(i).getAge());
        list3.add(obj); 
    }
}
```

or just simply add the `Surname` property to `Object1` and loop over list2 to add the Sirnames.

Comment: Attribute must begin with lowerCase charactere in Java classes

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that your Ovject1 class has 3 attributes : name, age and surname. I sugget too that it has getters and setters.

You can do a same loop on your two lists and take the data from second list and put on the first one. You might check if the two lists have the same size before.

```
int size=list1.size();
List<Object1> list3 = new ArrayList<Object1>();
for(int i=0;i < size;i++){
    object1 = list1.get(i);
    object1.setSurname(list2.get(i));
    list3.add(object1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use Jackson to make a Map from your Object1/Object2...ObjectN and merge Maps then, it's also known as map/reduce pattern.

Map phase: convert you object to instance of java.util.Map

Reduce phase: merge Map objects

optionally you can serialize result Map to your domain class again.

Check out this example, it does do exactly what you want: https://dumpz.org/2707215/

Comment: I get that code, but i have an error on List.of:

         Multiple markers at this line
 - The method of(JacksonDemo.UserPersonalDetails, 
       JacksonDemo.UserPersonalDetails) is undefined for the 
  type List
 - Line breakpoint:JacksonDemo [line: 55] - main(String[])

Comment: use java9 or replace List.of with Java8 analog